# ng-repeat in a directive is being linked outside the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

(Lots of similar questions/answers, but couldn't find a solution to this)

Trying to created nested directives. The issue is that the inner directives are being placed above the outer directive.

```
angular.module('mayofest14ClientApp')
  .controller('OrderCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
      $scope.order = {
        activities: [
          {formattedTime: '2014-03-04', performedBy: 'matt', action: 'Action', comment: 'Some comment'},
        ],
      };

    }
  ])
  .directive('orderActivity', [function () {

    return {
      scope: {
        activities: '=',
      },
      replace:true,
      restrict: 'E',
      template:
        '<div class="order_activity">' +
        '   <table>' +
        '       <caption>order_id History</caption>' +
        '       <thead>' +
        '           <tr>' +
        '               <th>Date</th>' +
        '           </tr>' +
        '       </thead>' +
        '       <tbody>' +
        '           <p ng-repeat="record in activities" record="record">Order activity {{record.action}} (This is where I want to call a nested directive)</p>' +
        '' +
        '       </tbody>' +
        '   </table>' +
        '</div>',
    };
  }]);
```

And the HTML,

```
<order-activity activities="order.activities"></order-activity>
```

The result is, the `p` tag with the `ng-repeat` is appearing before the template in the `orderActivity` directive.

I've read stuff about using transclude, messing with replace, some people mentioned using `$timeout`'s or `$watch`'s to adjust the order. The latter especially seemed messy and I couldn't find a good example of it.

Essentially, what can I do to get this rendering in the proper order?

Should I build the link function to generate the template, and write in all the 'record in activities' it self and avoid the 'ng-repeat'?

Oh, this is Angular 1.2.16

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not sure this is a great solution)

The real motivation was to call an inner directive.  I had used a `p` tag in the question just to simplify.

In any case, I seemed to solve this by ensuring that the inner-directive was compiled before the outer directive.  I did this by using `$compile` and `$interpolate`, and by creating a scope for the inner directive.

My outer directive:

```
angular.module('mayofest14ClientApp')
.directive('orderActivity', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    var head = 
        '<div class="order_activity">' +
        '   <table>' +
        '       <caption>order_id History</caption>' +
        '       <thead>' +
        '           <tr>' +
        '               <th>Date</th>' +
        '               <th>Performed By</th>' +
        '               <th>Action</th>' +
        '               <th>Comment(s)</th>' +
        '           </tr>' +
        '       </thead>' +
        '       <tbody>\n';
    var body = '';
    var foot = '        </tbody>' +
        '   </table>' +
            '</div>';

        return {
            scope: {
                activities: '=',
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            for (var i = 0; i<scope.activities.length; i++) {
                var itemScope = scope.$new(true);
            itemScope.record=scope.activities[i];
                body += $compile('<order-activity-item record="record"></order-activity-item>')(itemScope).html();
            }

            console.log("Compiling order-activity");
            element.html(
                $compile(head+body+foot)(scope)
            );
        }
    };
}]);
```

My inner directive:

```
angular.module('mayofest14ClientApp')
.directive('orderActivityItem', ['$compile', '$interpolate', function ($compile, $interpolate) {
    var template = '<tr><td>{{record.date}}</td><td>{{record.performedBy}}</td><td>{{record.action}}</td><td>{{record.comment}}</td></tr>';
    return {
        scope: {
            record: '=',
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        compile: function compile(element, attributes) {
            console.log('orderItem (compile)');
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, element, attributes) {
                    console.log('orderItem (pre-link)');
                    element.html($interpolate(template)(scope));
                },
                post: function postLink(scope, element, attributes) {
                    console.log('orderItem (post-link)');
                }
            };
        },
    };
}]);
```

So the important parts here are that:
- I'm creating a scope, and giving it the `record` object read by the inner directive
- In the inner directive `compile` function, it `$interpolate`s the values into the html, and then compiles it
- The compiled and interpolated HTML is returned to the linking of the outer directive
- The outer directive is then built.

I have not yet checked for memory errors or anything, nor do I know yet if doing this will impact performance in a negative way.

The reason I chose outer/inner directives is that I'd like the inner directives to have actions on it (click to modify, etc..), and this is how I would lay out the objects in a proper OO design.  Not sure if directives should reflect OO architecture though.

Solutions I saw elsewhere used `$watch`'s and `$on`s, some even used `$timeout`s.  The latter seems messy and unpredictable, while the former seems odd..  In any case I wasn't really able to get those working.

Comment: I've found it easier to just have one big directive, rather than a big outer one calling inner directives.  This would obviously not apply to some requirements, but for mine it seems to work a lot better.